# RabbitMQ. Routing within one queue

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I develop an application in Java. The idea is to use a single queue to process messages sequentially. I have different reports that I send to exchange and then to the queue. The consumer should use different handlers depending on the type of message (I use routing keys for this).

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "reports", containerFactory = "reportsFactory")
    public void processUniversalReport(Message message) {
        String routingKey = message.getMessageProperties().getReceivedRoutingKey();
        switch (routingKey) {
            case "grades.for.period.report":
                smartReportsDAO.processChecksReport(message);
                break;
            case "checks.full.card.report":
                smartReportsDAO.processGradesForPeriodReport(message);
                break;
```

The problem is to make the routing work, I have to add duplicate bindings records with different routing keys to the definitions.json

```
{
  "source": "direct-reports",
  "vhost": "/",
  "destination": "reports",
  "destination_type": "queue",
  "routing_key": "grades.for.period.report",
  "arguments": {
  }
},
{
  "source": "direct-reports",
  "vhost": "/",
  "destination": "reports",
  "destination_type": "queue",
  "routing_key": "checks.full.card.report",
  "arguments": {
  }
},
```

What do you think, maybe my idea to use routing keys was wrong?

Comment: I figured out, all you need to do is to use the queue type = topic and specify the wildcard # as value for routing key. https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-java.html

Comment: Why wouldn't you embed the routing key(or whatever property that separates messages) inside your messages and use simple fanout exchanges with one consumer binding?